# Xamarin change searchbar underline color and Icon Spacing Fix

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Ok so i want to change the gray underline of the searchbar to another color

[image: searchbar picture]

Because i tried to use this code in a custom render

```
        var plateId = Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
        var plate = Control.FindViewById(plateId);
        plate.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
```

But it removes the underline and changes the background color (Not what I want)[image: Searchar Image 2]

If I change the color to Transparent it looks like this (And I just want to change color...)
[image: Searchbar image 3]

Bonus side question: How do I change the Spacing on the Left of the searchbar icon (this is the code I use to change the image)

```
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var icon = Control?.FindViewById(Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null));
        (icon as ImageView)?.SetColorFilter(Color.DimGray.ToAndroid());
```

Comment: For people wandering why I want the color change is because the colors in the emulator appeared gray, but in my physical device they appeared white...

Comment: this has been asked numerous times: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+search_plate+underline+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: huh so the app underline being the wrong color is apparently a bug, i did try the code that you merged and it just gave me errors...